# svg <a> element not working

Tags: html, svg, d3.js, anchor

I need to add a link `<a>` inside a rectangle. I am basing my work on the [Collapsible Indented Tree example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093025) . However, when I add the `<a>` element with the inner `<text>` element, although they do get displayed, they don't behave as a regular `<a>` element meaning that the cursor does not change to a pointer and the click does nothing at all. Below is the code I added in order to achieve this:

```
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("svg:g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { 
      return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; 
   })
  .style("opacity", 1e-6);

// Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
nodeEnter.append("svg:rect")
  .attr("y", -barHeight / 2)
  .attr("height", barHeight)
  .attr("width", barWidth)
  .style("fill", color)
  .on("click", click);

nodeEnter.append("svg:text")
  .attr("dy", 3.5)
  .attr("dx", 5.5)
  .text(function(d) { return d.code + ' - ' + d.name; });

//THIS IS THE CODE I ADDED
var $a = nodeEnter.append("svg:a")
.attr("xlink:href", function(d){
  return 'http://www.mysite.com?q=' + d.id;
}).attr("target", "_blank");

$a.append("svg:text")
.attr("x", 200).attr("y", 5.5)
.text(function(d) { return 'Ver Detalles' });
//HERE ENDS THE CODE I ADDED
```

The rectangle itself has a listener for the 'click' event which works perfectly fine.

The generated SVG is:

```
<g class="node" transform="translate(57.14285659790039,175)" style="opacity: 1;">
    <rect y="-12.5" height="25" width="768" style="fill: #ffffff;"></rect>
    <text dy="3.5" dx="5.5">Hello World</text>
    <a xlink:href="http://www.mysite.com?q=8" target="_blank">
        <text x="200" y="5.5">Click Me</text>
    </a>
</g>
```

Apparently this looks like valid SVG but again, the anchor element is not working at all. Did anyone run into something like this before?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue which was inherited by the example Collapsible Indented Tree. Actually it is not a bug on the example itself but rather a css declaration that prevented the pointer events from triggering.

I found the following CSS declaration:

```
.node text {
    font: 12px sans-serif;
    pointer-events: none;  // <- this was preventing the `<a>` element from triggering  events
 }
```

After removing the `pointer-events: none;` declaration anchor elements began to work as expected.